# prevent side menu in SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create single page application . I'm using react router and side menu . some page doesn't need side menu. in app file, I prevent call side menu component for this page. but it doesn't work until page refresh. how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, when you say "some page doesn't need side menu", I'm confused, because you said you're creating a single page application. If it truly is a single page application and that application doesn't require a side menu, how can it be that "some page doesn't need side menu"? If you don't need it at all, how about completely removing the side menu from the render so that it doesn't show up at all?

Comment: thanks for your response. I have 20 page. but 2 page doesn't need side menu. is it reasonable to remove sidebar ?